# How to search for documents which has a specific attribute inside hash Mongoid 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, hash, mongoid

Imagine the following Model:

```
class Model
  ...
  field :things,    type Hash
  ...
end
```

I would like then to be able to search for documents which has a specific attribute inside the `things` hash like so:

```
model = Model.where('things.order_id' => 9689689)
```

or

```
model = Model.where('things.order_id' => 9689689).all
```

But that doesn't find the document(s) I'm looking for. Neither does the following:

```
model = Model.elem_match(inside: {order_id: 116152})
```

nor this one:

```
model = Model.where(:inside.elem_match => {order_id: 116152})
```

What am I missing here?

Please note this is not an embedded document, but simply a model which contains hashes (though would be nice to find a way to do similar searches in embedded models).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
model = Model.where(:'things.order_id' => 9689689)
```

Comment: I got a `NoMethodError: undefined method `eq' for "things.order_id":String` when I tried your suggestion

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't find the document. PS: The 9689689 represents an actual document in the db, so it definitely should return at least one document. I get nothing back.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made clearer: my second comment was in regards to your updated answer. So no, it doesn't work with your updated answer I'm afraid.

Comment: No, but it doesn't find any document either (and there's a document that matches the criteria)

Comment: What about this answer?

Comment: Still doesn't work. It gives me an empty Mongoid criteria object (with no results).